# Using dplyr group_by in a function

Tags: r, function, group-by, dplyr, nse

I am trying to use dplyr's group_by in a local function, example:

```
testFunction <- function(df, x) {
  df %>%
group_by(x) %>%
summarize(mean.Petal.Width = mean(Petal.Width))
}

testFunction(iris, Species)
```

and I get an error "... unknown variable to group by: x"
I've tried group_by_ and it gives me a summary of the entire dataset.
Anybody have a clue how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to work with the new `enquo` from `dplyr`, where `enquo` takes the string and converts to `quosure` which gets evaluated by unquoting (`UQ` or `!!`) in `group_by`, `mutate`, `summarise` etc.

```
library(dplyr)
testFunction <- function(df, x) {
 x <- enquo(x)
  df %>%
    group_by(!! x) %>%
     summarize(mean.Petal.Width = mean(Petal.Width))
 }

testFunction(iris, Species)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#     Species mean.Petal.Width
#      <fctr>            <dbl>
#1     setosa            0.246
#2 versicolor            1.326
#3  virginica            2.026
```

Comment: cool. That works, thank you very much. Do you have a reference url that covers this?

Comment: @RoseS  You can check [here](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#quoting)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work like this:

```
testFunction <- function(df, x) {
                      df %>%
                         group_by(get(x)) %>%
                         summarize(mean.Petal.Width = mean(Petal.Width))
                 }

testFunction(iris,"Species")
```

I changed `x` to `get(x)`, and `Species` to `"Species"` in `testFunction(iris,...)`.

Comment: I tried 20 things, so don't ask me why it works...;)

Comment: hmmm, I think the 'get(x)' helps... it seems to understand what to group by now. Now I get the error ".... object "Species" not found" , so I'm not able to get it to work with or without quotes when calling the function. Do you have an idea why that might work for you?  Ha! I just saw "...don't ask me how it works"

Comment: Do you have `dplyr` loaded? Updated `dplyr`? You could also try `akrun` answer...which should be equivalent.

Comment: I did not have the updated dplyr loaded until after seeing Akrun's response, so that might be it. Thank you so much for your help!